# Loop for Drawing Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I appreciate anyone's help on this as I am new to Python. The script below will draw a triangle with 3 mouse clicks. I want to alter this script with a loop to allow unlimited mouse clicks. Can someone help me on the next steps? A picture of what I want it to do is provided below the script.

```
import graphics as g
def main():
    win=g.GraphWin("Draw a Triangle")
    win.setCoords(0.0,0.0,100.0,100.0)
    message=g.Text(g.Point(50,50),"Click on three points")
    message.draw(win)


    p1=win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p2=win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    p3=win.getMouse()
    p3.draw(win)

    triangle=g.Polygon(p1,p2,p3)
    triangle.setFill("Red")
    triangle.setOutline("cyan")
    triangle.draw(win)

    message.setText("click anywhere to quit.")
    win.getMouse()
main()

print(main)
```

Below is what I would like it to do. On my 2nd mouse click it will automatically draw the point and a line between the first and second point. Then the same for point 3, point 4, etc.with the option for unlimited points.

[image: Polygon Example]

Comment: You need to decide how the program will know to stop the polyline. In your example, it is done when the user clicks on the first point. How close must that click be to the first point to be considered on the first point? Is that the only way to end the connected segments? How about the user pressing the Escape key to end the segments? Or clicking a button to stop? And so on. You need to decide those items then add them to your problem description. You should look at commercial drawing programs to see how they handle this part of the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to keep track of the points the user has clicked, and to clear the canvas when re-drawing the objects.

The `graphics.py` file you are using seems to be from [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py). The code in turn is just a wrapper around [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

Therefore, just familiarise yourself with how TkInter handles mouse and keypresses and you should be able to do what you want. For e.g., rather than use `win.getMouse()`, the preferred way to use a GUI framework is to bind functions (event handlers) to specific events as I demonstrate below.

```
import graphics as g

def main():

    win = g.GraphWin("Draw a polygon")
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
    message = g.Text(g.Point(50, 50), "Click to add point to polygon")
    message.draw(win)

    # Set of points clicked so far
    points = []
    def onClick(pt):
        x, y = win.toWorld(pt.x, pt.y)
        points.append(g.Point(x, y))
        poly = g.Polygon(*points)

        # Clear all objects on canvas.
        # You can choose to delete only current polygon by associating a label with it.
        # See Tkinter's documentation for details
        win.delete("all")

        poly.setFill("Red")
        poly.setOutline("Cyan")
        poly.draw(win)

    win.setMouseHandler(onClick)

    # This is not idea as we are wasting cycles doing polling
    # I believe Tkinter should have a better approach to avoid this.
    while not win.checkKey() == 'q':
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```